# Best practice to bundle .py files

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python programming, I'm used to C++; I guess this is answered before, but I cannot find it. I use Python(x,y), which runs on Spyder.

I have a couple of related long functions in separated .py files. The functions rely on the same modules. I would like the user to be able to call these functions from the IPython console. Preferably, the user can run a single command to make all functions available. What is the most common way to do this? I can put a whole bunch of 'import' commands in the main of a file, but this seems not very elegant. Creating a project (or a module) may work, but I can't find any good documentation and it seems a bit overkill.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Module is exactly what you need, and it is not hard at all, see:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user to be able to import your functions like:

```
import your_module
```

and then access your functions as `your_module.function_a` and `your_module.function_b`, even if `function_a` lives in one file and `function_b` lives in another.

Use a directory module which is a directory with a `__init__.py` file. Like this:

```
- your_module
  |- __init__.py
  |- function_a.py
  \- function_b.py
```

In that file `__init__.py` you can include import statements such as:

```
from function_a import function_a
from function_b import function_b
```

Note that this would also support doing `from your_module import *` but I would recommended using `import your_module as short_name` instead where possible.